# How to register a dependency injection with a class which takes constructor parameters

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor

I would like to inject a specific instance of a class `Dependency` via dependency injection with `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

The problem is that I don't want to inject `new Dependency()`, but pass parameters to (one of) its constructor such as `new Dependency(parameters);`.

The Dependency and the Dependant() classes

```
public class Dependency // I don't want (or rather have the possibility) to define an interface
{
    public Dependency(object parameters) // No parameterless constructor
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class Dependant()
{
    private Dependency _object;
    
    public Example(Dependency object)
    {
        _object = object;
    }
}
```

The service provider.

```
private static ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

private void RegisterServices()
{
    // var parameters = ...

    var services = new ServiceCollection();
        .AddSingleton<Depandency>(); // Is it possible to pass the parameters to Dependency instance via a lambda expression for example?
    
    _serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
}
```

Is it possible to pass the parameters to Dependency instance via a lambda expression for example?

Thanks for any insights !

Comment: Crucial to your question is to know whether this `object` parameter is something that is determined at startup (and remains constant) or is something that changes at runtime (for instance because it is supplied as input by a web request). Both answers that are given at this point assume the parameter is a startup constant.

Comment: True enough. I did not precise it, but `object` is determined at startup and is not supposed to change at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parameters are known during application startup (when all dependencies are being registered), then you should be able to use lambda

```
services.AddSingleton<Depandency>(provider => new Dependency(parameter));
```

If parameters are known only when dependency is used, then you can create a "factory" class

```
public class DependencyFactory
{
  public Dependency Create(object parameter) => new Dependency(parameter);
}

services.AddSingleton<DependencyFactory>();

public class Consumer
{
   public Consumer(DependencyFactory factory) 
   {
     _factory = factory
   }

   public void Use()
   {
     var dependency = _factory.Create(parameter);
     // use dependency
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll also keep in mind the possibility to use a factory for future uses. I'm just wondering, if `object` changes, it is independently of the **Singleton** or should rather a **Transient DI** be used?

Comment: For first option with transient registration same lambda with original instance of the object will be used to create a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to pass the parameters to Dependency instance via a lambda expression for example?

Yes:

```
.AddSingleton(services => new Dependency(new object()));
```

Although using `object` as a parameter is unlikely to be useful.

You should look at specifying an interface for the object that `Dependency` requires, and registering an implementation with the container.